# Preloding apis shows "not used within a few seconds" waring in safari 12, but wroks fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, safari, preload

While trying to preload APIs, met with following warning in safari

> The resource https://hots.com/test/api was preloaded using link
>   preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load
>   event. Please make sure it wasn't preloaded for nothing.

Also, APIs are firing twice.

But this API response is using immediately on the same page. and its work fine in Chrome without any warning. Issue is seen in safari 12 and according to https://caniuse.com/#search=preload preload is fully supported in safari. My implementation is given below

```
<script>             
    function preload(api) {

        if(api) { 
            var preloadLink = document.createElement("link");
            preloadLink.href = api;
            preloadLink.rel = "preload";
            preloadLink.as = "fetch";
            preloadLink.setAttribute("crossorigin", "");
            document.head.appendChild(preloadLink);
        }
    }

    preload('/test/api');
</script>
```

Is there any way to fix this warning ?